# Pointer to class, implementing multiple interfaces

Tags: c++11, inheritance

```
class I1 {};
class I2 {};
class C : public I1, public I2 {};
C c;
I1 *i = static_cast<I1*>(&c);
C *p = static_cast<C*>(i);
```

I am trying to understand if casting between object pointer and interface pointer is safe.

- Is the above code wrong? Are there problems with object slicing and why?
- Is `static_cast` the appropriate cast here?
- Are the binary representations of `i` and `p` the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK.  There's no slicing because you are casting pointers, not class types.  Note that the cast is not even needed here:

```
I1 *i = static_cast<I1*>(&c);
```

`static_cast` is an appropriate cast for the other direction:

```
C *p = static_cast<C*>(i);
```

If your interface classes have virtual methods (which they typically would in a real program), you could also use `dynamic_cast` if you are unsure about the type of `i` until runtime:

```
if (C *p = dynamic_cast<C*>(i)) {
    // use p
}
```

The point of `dynamic_cast` is that it uses RTTI to find out if the cast is valid.  If not, it will return null.  If you use `static_cast` and the type is not correct at runtime, you have undefined behavior.

The binary value of the derived class pointer will likely be the same as the binary value of its first base class, but not its second one.  But you should not care about such implementation details.